# Jax RS with Spring boot applicaton

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, server-sent-events

Working on a spring boot based application there is a requirement to add server sent events in the application. While browsing, I came across a solution using jaxrs. The question her is, can we use spring-boot-starter-jaxrs, spring-boot-starter-web dependency in the same gradle project?

Comment: They should work fine together. Also, there is no spring-boot-starter-jaxrs dependency. There is a cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs and spring-boot-starter-jersey. The latter is the officially (Spring Boot) supported one. If you have a specific problem using these two together, please post a specific question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Paul. My use case is, I need to push notification to UI on completion of certain events on Spring application. I came across multiple implementations. Not sure if there is any best way based on use case.